# why is last4 after now prints3 and before working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, event-loop

```
console.log("first");
let a=0
const main =async()=>{
    a++
    console.log("start" + a);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        a++;
        console.log("time out_--" + a);
    },0)
    
    a++
    console.log("end" + a)
    let ab =await hello();
    console.log(ab);
   
    
}

const hello = async()=>{
        
    for(let i=0 ; i<=1000000000 ; i++)
    {
        if(i==1000000000)
        {
            a++
            console.log("now prints" + a);
        }
    }
 
    return "working...."
}
main();
a++
console.log("last" + a);
```

output for the above code is

```
first
start1
end2
now prints3
last4
working
time out_--5
```

why is last4 after now prints3 and before working.
i want to understand how event loop actually works. Because the output of above code is confusing me a lot.